# material ui stack center and right top

Tags: layout, material-ui, stack, alignment

I try to make such layout with Material UI (V5):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HBnIx.png)

I tested Stack and Grid but cannot align both the button in the center and the left text on the top right.
Any suggestions?

Mark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the code below and this working [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/fullwidthgrid-demo-material-ui-forked-j7xchq?file=/demo.tsx)

You can create a `Grid` with 3 fragments in a row leaving empty the first one and giving it the same column width property as the last one (in this case `sx={1}` just as an example).

```
import * as React from "react";
import Grid from "@mui/material/Grid";
import Button from "@mui/material/Button";

export default function FullWidthGrid() {
  return (
    <Grid container direction="row" sx={{ background: "grey" }}>
      <Grid item xs={1} />
      <Grid container xs={10} justifyContent="center">
        <Button variant="contained">Contained</Button>
      </Grid>
      <Grid item xs={1}>
        TextX
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
  );
}
```

I would suggest to study the [Grid MUI V5](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-grid/) as it gives you much flexibility so understanding it would save you more time in the future.

Another solution would be to have a wrapper `<div>` component for example, with `position: relative` and inside it to have a `Typography` component with `align="center"` and another `<span>TextX</span>` with `position: absolute` and position it on the top right.

Comment: thank you Akis for the solutions.